# Delivery Notification to alternate email address

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, smtp

I'm trying to write a simple form that will send system emails through SMTP to various users they select from a generic email account in an ASP.NET MVC3 web application.  This account is a gmail account currently but is probably going to change to another domain once we publish this project.

Is there a way to send a delivery failure notification email to any email address other than the generic email account that is used to send the emails that is available in ASP.NET?

Here's the code I've used.  I've already tried a few of the solutions that involve headers but am not getting much success. For the example, the email address I'm trying to send the delivery failure notification emails is test@email.com (the actual address to use would be pulled from the user's login)

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Mailer.Smtp.User"], "Mailer");

mail.To.Add(to);
mail.Subject = Subject;
mail.Body = Body;
mail.IsBodyHtml = true; // to incorporate the editor into it
mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(From));
mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(From);
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
mail.Headers.Add("Read-Receipt-To", "test@email.com");
mail.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "test@email.com");

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Duplicate?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12793790/532498