# Delivery Status Notification & Read Receipt in SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, email

How can I request Delivery Status Notification in SMTP
and how can I parse it?
I,m using this as

```
mailmessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
```

Mailing is success,but I'm not getting any delivery status.

Can anyone identify the reason ?

By using

```
message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "emailid");
```

The read receipt is received,
Could I set the content of the read receipt in the original message?

Thanks in advance for any help...!!!

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793790/delivery-notification-in-smtp)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can do this by adding **smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;**
the the code like this :

```
            mm.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", smtp_user);
            mm.Headers.Add("Return-Receipt-To", smtp_user);

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtp_address, smtp_port);
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtp_user, smtp_password);
            smtp.EnableSsl = smtp_ssl;

            smtp.Send(mm);
```