# Mails Delivery Notifications in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am sending mails to various clients in my application. I need to get the notification mail of sent(read/not read) or failed mails. Following is the code i have used to do the same:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(txtemail.Text, MyEmail, txtsubject.Text, myString);
 message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess;
 message.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
 message.Headers.Add("Disposition-NotificationTo", txtemail.Text);
```

I have used both OnSucess as well as onFailure DeliveryNotificationOptions so that i could get notifications for both the cases.Is is right to use this way?
If not than how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the link:
[Delivery Notification in SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793790/delivery-notification-in-smtp)
It explains what you should do to get a success or failure notification.