# C#-mailmessage: get Delivery Status Notification to different email address

Tags: c#, email, mailmessage

Is it possible to set a different email to receive the Delivery Status Notification in C#? I tried setting the ReplyToList but didn't work as I wanted.
I use gmail provider.

```
MailMessage emailMessage = new MailMessage();
emailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myacc@gmail.com");
emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("accto@gmail.com"));
emailMessage.Subject = "SUBJECT";
emailMessage.Body = "BODY";
emailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
SmtpClient MailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
MailClient.EnableSsl = true;
MailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myacc@gmail.com", "mypass");
MailClient.Send(emailMessage);
```

There is no a clear answer if such header exists or not in other questions.

Comment: please show code.. this is very broad in nature and very poor question at best in it's current state. Thanks

Comment: well I added code but I dont think that it makes any difference..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delivery Notification in SMTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793790/delivery-notification-in-smtp)

Comment: @hatchet its not duplicate cause there is no accepted answer in the post you proposed as duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it's commonly claimed to achieve this is

```
mailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess | DeliveryNotificationOPtions.OnFailure;
mailMessage.AddHeaderField( "Return-Receipt-To" , "\"John Doe\" <johnDoe@blahblahblah.com>" );
mailMessage.AddHeaderField( "Disposition-Notification-To" , "\"John Doe\" <johnDoe@blahblahblah.com>" );
```

But there is no guarantee the request will be honored by the mail servers or the recipient.

The `Disposition-Notification-To` header field is the standard way, and `Return-Receipt-To` is non-standard.