# How do I know if a sent email was delivered using c# SmtpClient and MailMessage?

Tags: c#

How do I know if a sent email was delivered using C# `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage`? Is there a way to get a response back?

Comment: When would you expect to get such a response? The e-mail isn't necessarily propagated to the recipient's mail server during your request to your own SMTP server. If you don't get an exception, the e-mail made it to your SMTP server. You'd need to use a service that gives you per-message delivery visibility to know more, and that wouldn't be in real time.

Comment: try add your own email as bcc, and see  if you got the email

Comment: Multiple recipients (of any kind, since SMTP doesn't distinguish them, only the headers do) could receive the message by different mail exchanges, so BCC-ing yourself won't tell you anything about other recipients, only that the message could be delivered *to you*.

Comment: That's not to say that you shouldn't BCC yourself or that it's not a useful diagnostic tool -- do it if you want -- just make sure your expectations are correct when you do. Don't assume that other recipients had the same experience that you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practical answer: no. Technical answer: it depends and it's not worth it. Very well explained here: [Delivery Notification in SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793790/delivery-notification-in-smtp).

Also, I think your system shouldn't take on the responsibility of checking if the email was delivered or not to the user. Just let the servers handle that. There could be a million reasons why an email didn't go through or arrived at spam or made it a few moments, minutes, hours later.

Just make sure your sending method ends well. If you're using an external provider, just check you get a successful response from them (even in those cases, you might get a 200 response and they might fail for some weird reason to deliver the email).